# Laravel Conditional route filter

Tags: laravel

Hey guys could you please help me? This one is driving me crazy...

Let's say that I have a method for checking if the user is an admin or not:

```
    public function isAdmin()
{
    return Auth::user()->role === 'admin';
}
```

Then I attach it to a route filter:

```
    Route::filter('admin', function($route, $request)
{
    if ( ! Auth::user()->isAdmin()) {

        Notification::error('No permission to view this page!');
        return Redirect::back();
    }
});
```

Now, I just pass it to the route group

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'admin'), function()
  {
    Route::post('users/{id}/update_password', 'UserController@update_password');
    Route::post('users/{id}/delete', 'UserController@force_delete');
    Route::delete('users/{id}', array('as' => 'users.destroy', 'uses' => 'UserController@destroy'));
    Route::post('users/{id}/restore', 'UserController@restore');
    Route::get('users/create', array('as' => 'users.create', 'uses' => 'UserController@create'));
    Route::post('users', array('as' => 'users.store', 'uses' => 'UserController@store'));
    Route::get('users/{id}/edit', array('as' => 'users.edit', 'uses' => 'UserController@edit'));
    Route::put('users/{id}', array('as' => 'users.update', 'uses' => 'UserController@update'));
  });
```

The question here is how do I allow a user to bypass this filter if for example he's trying to update **it's own** profile page an obviously he's not and admin?
I just want to block all access to the users routes for nonadmins but allow the user to edit/update etc on his own profile but allow the admin to do that too.

Could you please point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this, but having a filter that checks the request segments against the currently authenticated user isn't the best way.

**Choice Number 1**

You simply check that a user is auth'd (use the `auth` filter), and then in the controller itself you check whether or not the user is an admin, and/or it's their profile.

**Choice Number 2**

Define a secondary sets of routes specifically for a user modifying their own profile, that doesn't follow the `/user/{id}/*` pattern.

```
Route::group(['before' => 'admin'], function() {
    // admin routes here
}

Route::group(['prefix' => '/me'], function() {
    Route::post('/update_password', 'UserController@update_password');
    Route::post('/delete', 'UserController@force_delete');
    // etc
}
```

This would mean that to edit their own profile, they could simply go to `/me/edit` rather than `/user/{id}/edit`. To avoid issues like repeating the same code, or errors because an argument is missing, you could do something like this in your controller.

```
private function getUserOrMe($id)
{
    return $id !== false ? User::find($id) : Auth::user();
}

public function edit($id = false)
{
    $user = $this->getUserOrMe($id);
}
```

I recently used this particular method for an API. Sure it requires defining the routes again, but providing that you've set them up with groups that make use of the `prefix` option, it's a copy and paste job, plus, there are routes an admin would have that a user wouldn't.

Either way, filters weren't intended to do complex logic, but rather, to provide a level of base logic and protection for routes. Logic that identifies whether the current uri is that of the currently logged in user, is something better handled in a controller.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the related request segment to check it in your filter:

```
Route::filter('admin', function($route, $request)
{
    if ( ! Auth::user()->isAdmin() && Auth::user()->username !== Request::segment(2)) {
        Notification::error('No permission to view this page!');
        return Redirect::back();
    }
});
```